# $(this).val() method isn't returning the right value for the selected id

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm in the elementary stages of learning Django meshed with AJAX and am so very close to completing my application which is just a simple dependent dropdown with countries and cities. I've run into a bit of a head-scratching problem though. The numerical value that I am trying to grab from my ***'select_countries'*** selector isn't returning a numerical value, but the actual country itself, which is preventing my AJAX call from working properly as it's expecting an integer. 
I'm pulling the cities linked to each country from my database by the country's numerical id and not the name so this obviously presents a problem for me.

I hard coded the id of 1 (representing England) into the ***countryId*** variable and verified that my AJAX call is indeed working and returning the cities it should in the ***'select_cities'*** selector, which is handled in a separate html template. I just need to fix the small issue shown below in the picture.

I did some searching on SO and found that some people managed to resolve similar issues by changing ***.val()*** to **.data("value")** and .**attr("value")** like so.

```
 var countryId = $(this).attr("value")

 or

 var countryId = $(this).data("value")
```

Unfortunately, all this is doing is storing a value of undefined in countryId. This is allowing the ajax call to execute properly, but it's not returning any options in the 'select_cities' selector.

[image: Code problem]
[image: Code HTML]

As you can see, var CountryId should be storing 2, and not Ireland.
Anyone have any ideas as to what the issue could be?

Comment: It should be `<option value="1">England</option>` and so on. `value` instead of `val`

Comment: jquery .val returns the value, not the `val` attribute.  Use `$(this).find("option:selected").attr("val")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val` isn't a valid attribute here:

```
<option val="1">England</option>
```

The attribute name should be `value`.  Since there's no `value`, the default is the content of the element, which in this case is `'England'`.

To get the value from `.val()` it needs to be a valid `value` attribute:

```
<option value="1">England</option>
```

Comment: I'm a dunce. That was it. Thank you! I'll accept when the 7 minute timer block expires -_-

Answer (score -2):

You want something like this?

```
$("#selectcountries").change(() => {
    var selectedCountry = $(this).attr('val');
    alert("You have selected the country - " + selectedCountry);
});
```

Comment: There is no `val` attribute on a `<select>`